# Installing nginx breaks HTTP requests for OpenCPU

Tags: r, opencpu

I'm trying to install the cache server for OpenCPU (I need to enable caching) on an Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 instance. A dependency of opencpu-cache is the latest version of nginx (I can't install the cache server without it).

After I had already installed OpenCPU and verified that it was working, I installed nginx and then opencpu-cache. After installation, however, I can no longer make HTTP or HTTPS requests to the server. Entering both the public IP address and public DNS from the AWS console into my web browser fails to yield a landing page for the server, whereas it was working fine before I installed nginx.

My security rules on AWS are set up correctly (i.e. they're allowing the right ports for HTTP and HTTPS), so what is the issue? All my packages on the server are also up-to-date. SSH sessions work just fine still. I just can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: What do you see for `sudo service opencpu-cache restart`

Comment: @Jeroen Wait thanks that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it turns out that `sudo service opencpu-cache restart` did the trick lol. Props to Jeroen above.